# How to prevent On Send add-in errors when user clicks elsewhere?

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've created an outlook add-in with the "On-Send feature" as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows).

Everything works fine on the web version of Outlook, but on the desktop there are some issues.

When a user sends a message and then quickly selects another message, the send action fails and the user gets this error.

[image: An add-in prevented this message from being sent. It will be saved as a draft.]

If the reply is popped out, the user gets a different error.

[image: Add-ins are still running on this message. The message won't be sent until the add-in completes. Do you want to wait for them to finish?]

Testing the [Microsoft sample application](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send) demonstrates these same issues.

How can these behaviors, or at least the first error, be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are valid, and aren't able to be avoided. If your add-in hasn't finished, and the user closes the item, then they are warned the email hasn't actually been sent yet. Please be sure that your add-in calls `event.completed()` to notify Outlook your add-in action has completed.